# How can I change the alias in Nginx depending on the url arguments?

Tags: nginx

I have location:

```
location = /conf.js {
alias /config/conf.js;
}
```

I want to make sure that if URL contains the arg1 argument(for example https://test.com?arg1=4982948394) alias = /config/conf2.js, in all other cases /config/conf.js

Is it possible to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
map $arg_arg1 $conf {
    4982948394  /config/conf2.js;
    default     /config/conf.js;
}

server {
    ...
    location = /conf.js {
        alias $conf;
    }
    ...
```

The [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive allows regex matching, to check the `arg1` request query argument against any non-empty value you can use

```
map $arg_arg1 $conf {
    ~.          /config/conf2.js;
    default     /config/conf.js;
}
```

To check if the `arg1` argument is present in your request query string you can use the following `map` block:

```
map $args $conf {
    ~(^|&)arg1(=|&|$)  /config/conf2.js;
    default            /config/conf.js;
}
```

You can check the list of all nginx internal variables [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

Comment: Thanks. But in this example, "map" is fixed to the value 4982948394. Is it possible to make any value arg1 to consider? Or the fact that the arg1 argument exists